# change position of image view

Tags: android, imageview

i can't change the position of the login button.Because when i try, it can't be moved from the original position. I' ve set the `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` but i want it in a specific position.

*how i can set the coordinates (x,y) of the image?*

this is the login_fragment.xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:src="@drawable/login_button" />
```

Comment: Where do you want to place the image view? at which corner or where?

Comment: deciding co-ordinate changes as the system changes

Comment: i want to place it in a specific position neither in a corner nor at the bottom or at the top

Comment: But it will not be good

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cant do it within the xml itself, you need to create an instance of that `ImageView` in your activity and call its `setX()` or `setY()` method to set the coordinates.

**Beware** that every screen has different number of pixels, you might have different result on different devices.

**Sample:**

```
ImageView s = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
s.setY(number);
s.setX(number);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(700);
animation.setRepeatCount(5);
animation.setRepeatMode(2);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
image.startAnimation(animation);
```